# where is the executable file for ggts?

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I only see the zip file in the windows icon on this page https://spring.io/tools/ggts/all  I only need the executable file

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the ZIP file and extract it. The GGTS.exe is inside.

Comment: Martin, thank you for your prompt reply, however, I get errors when I extract:  "An unexpected error is keeping you from copying the file. Error 0x80010135:  Path too long. pom.properties"

Comment: that could happen if you use Windows itself to extract the archive into a location with a certain path depth. Other zip tools like 7zip are able to extract the archive into those locations. Please use those if you run into this issue.

Comment: Thank you Martin.  it worked with 7 zip.  I appreciate your help.